# Luis V2 Remove action parameter/prompt

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

Since the version 2 update of LUIS we noticed that the service automatically ask the action parameter prompt first on a new intent and does not go to the actual intent in bot framework.

In the new LUIS dashboard there seems to be no mention of action parameters/prompts. How can we remove these from an intent is its preventing intents to fire from bot framework.

Changing the version in the LUISMODEL ( [LuisModel(xxxxxx", "xxxxxx",LuisApiVersion.V1)]) to version 1 solves our issue but would like to use version 2

Any help please?

Comment: FYI - I updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42583112/90081) and added a way to do Action Binding in the client, without LUIS.

Answer (score 1):

Action Parameters were deprecated, but from what you are seeing the change so far only affected the UI and not the response from LUIS which is still sending the information around parameters.

I believe the best way to overcome this at this point would be to delete the current intent and recreate it. Alternatively, you could explore [overriding things](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs#L219-L224) on the `LuisDialog`, however that might require more effort.

#### Update Apr-3

A new way of doing this in the client was published today. Check the blog post: [Implementing LUIS Action Binding on the Client](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/04/03/Luis-Action-Binding-Bot/)

Comment: seems to be a broken link

Answer (score 0):

With the new Luis Dashboard there is no mention of the old action parameters and prompts and no way to navigate to them.
So after some more digging and not wanting to do overrides i found that you can reassign intents with the new LUIS dashboard.

Here is what i did:

1. Create a new intent with the same name but just add 2 behind name:
   PolicyDocuments : PolicyDocuments2
2. Go into the initial intent and reassign all the intents to PolicyDocuments2.
3. Delete PolicyDocuments
4. Rename PolicyDocuments2 to PolicyDocuments
5. Train
6. Publish

Next time you hit that intent it wont ask you for the prompts defined in the intent

[image: Reassign INTENT]

[image: Rename/Delete Intent]

Hope this helps